# Protractor test not working with IE but it does with FF/Chrome/Safari

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, selenium, jasmine, protractor

I'm currently dealing with a problem with my protractor test against IE.

I'm using Protractor + Jasmine + Node.js

The portion of page that I'm testing is the following:

```
<h2 collapser="" class="title text-center text-uppercase active">Tech Specs <i class="plus-icon"></i></h2>
```

I've the following test:

```
it('User should be able to see module 11 Tech Specs collapsing and uncolapsing', function () {
    basePage.techSpecCollapser.click();
    browser.sleep(1000);
    expect(basePage.techSpecContainer.isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();

});
```

This is the console output:

```
 Landing page module verification -->
  User should be able to see module 11 Tech Specs collapsing and uncollapsing - fail


  1) New Landing page module verification --> User should be able to see module 11 Tech Specs collapsing and uncolapsing
  at 15.446s [Thu, 28 May 2015 14:23:08 GMT]
   Message:
     Expected false to be truthy.
   Stacktrace:
     Error: Failed expectation
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/Users/test/Documents/Dev/test/sandBox/specs/landing_page_spec.js:44:58)

Finished in 15.448 seconds
1 test, 1 assertion, 1 failure
```

By watching the test running, I saw that part of the web page is not getting displayed. I tried:

- Forcing scrolling to that section of the page: didn't work.
- Focusing that part of the page: didn't work.

Did anyone run into the same issue? can make it to work and it's very simple test!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple things you can try to solve it:

- maximize the browser window before running the tests. Add this to `onPrepare()`:

  ```
  browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
  ```
- remove the unreliable `browser.sleep()` and explicitly wait for the element to become visible with [`visibilityOf` expected condition](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions.prototype.visibilityOf):

  ```
  var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
  basePage.techSpecCollapser.click();
  browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(basePage.techSpecContainer), 10000);
  ```
- move to the element:

  ```
  browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", basePage.techSpecContainer.getWebElement());
  ```

Comment: Thanks @alecxe but I'm still getting the same output for this.  I've added all  what you suggested, one by one all what you suggested! but still seems not showing that part of the page, I was thinking that maybe is not clicking correctly the previous element.  what other suggestion you may have?

Comment: @BrunoSoko well, it is difficult to tell without being able to debug the problem. Another shot in the dark, try performing a click the following way: `browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", basePage.techSpecCollapser.getWebElement());`.

Comment: You're right. you are blindfolded on this, I came with different errors, but resolved some by adding this `browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100000);` con the config.js file and this on my test:
```basePage.subscribe.click().then(function () {
            browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(thxPage.thankYou), 90000);
            expect(thxPage.thankYou.isPresent()).toBeTruthy();
        });
```

Comment: But, I'm actually having another problem... the same logic does not work for another non-happy scenario... weired... this is what fails
        browser.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,10000)");
        basePage.email.sendKeys('bruno@test.com');
        basePage.subscribe.click().then(function () {
        browser.sleep(7000);
        basePage.confirmMessage('Contact already added to target campaign');});

Comment: @BrunoSoko thanks for sharing what helped to solve it. You can also try to scroll to view: `browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollToView()", basePage.email.getWebElement());`.

Comment: The problem that I had/have is only with the "blessed" IE, would you know why would I need to add more time for IE? why on this browser is slower?

Comment: @BrunoSoko yeah, with IE it is always something special and weird.